# Composition series for Z/nZ

Tags: abstract-algebra

Im going to have a midterm soon and don't understand how the I would go about solving this question. How would I find the normal subgroups of the quotient group Z/nZ?

Comment: Do you know what an abelian group is? Do you know any properties of subgroups of abelian groups?

Comment: Do you know how to find the subgroups of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, without the normality restriction?

Comment: This is *equivalent* to giving the prime factorization $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is abelian, so any subgroup is normal.  Thus, $\{<k>:   k | n\}$...